# No high refresh rates listed with Iris Xe, but works with NVIDIA

Tags: arch-linux, xrandr, intel-graphics, hdmi, edid

I have two laptops connected to the same monitor (Dell G3223D) via HDMI. Both laptops run Arch Linux. One laptop has an NVIDIA card (RTX 3080) and the other is an Iris Xe (i7-1260p). The monitor supports 165Hz refresh at 2560x1440, however only 144Hz is available via HDMI, which is fine.

The problem is that the laptop with the NVIDIA card can use 1440p at 120Hz and 144Hz with no issues, but the Iris Xe one can only use 60Hz at 1440p. If I boot the Xe laptop into Windows I can use 144Hz with no issues. Xrandr only reports 59.95Hz for 1440p on the Xe laptop, but on the NVIDIA laptop it reports all 3 refresh rates.

Any ideas?